# Get context path in init method in Servlet 2.3 (so no ServletContext#getContextPath() available)

Tags: servlets, init, contextpath

I'm using servlet 2.3 for my project development due to some legacy code we have. Is there a way to get the context path in the init method or any other way of the servlet?

I know it's possible on higher versions of Servlet and can get it in hacky way using the `getRealPath()` method on servlet 2.3. However I'm still looking for a better and cleaner code.

Comment: `ServletContext#getServletContextName()` was already added in 2.3? What newer method exactly was you talking about which you thought would solve your problem?

Comment: yeah, I saw this method. But I have set a display name in my web.xml and using this method returns the display name. I tried removing the display name tag and it does return me the context name alright. Just wondering if I can get the context name with keeping display name tag.

Comment: Don't you actually want the context path instead of the context name? I.e. the one which is available by `ServletContext#getContextPath()` since 2.5?

Comment: I'll put it down like this :- example -> `http://localhost:8888/mycontext/somepage`  - I want "/mycontext" only ..

Comment: That's the context path, not context name. I fixed the terminology in your question.

Comment: okay, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Method names already describe exactly what they return :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to do this. The best way I found was to move to 2.5 spec.

Posting answer just in case anyone is trying the same.